# What is the use of having three types of articles in the german language?(with example)

Tags: article

What is the idea behind having three types of articles for nouns in german language? What benefits german speaking people could get from it? What we gonna loose if we simplify all to "the" as the English language did? Can anybody provide an example of using different articles helps understanding better or making communication easier or preventing misunderstanding?

EDIT:
If we consider the creation of the articles in german language is the result of the normal procedure of language evolution, what is the reason behind evolving in this direction that we have now three types of articles?

Comment: The practical answer is ‘because langauge evolved that way’.

Comment: As we are talking about evolution so it is the matter of usefulness and what is the use of it? I mean is evolution keeps the better choice on the condition. What was the reason behind creating three types of articles?

Comment: What was the reason behind evolving in this direction that we have now three types of articles?

Comment: The three genders come from Proto-Indo-European, a language spoken thousands of years ago. It is not possible any more to identify the reasons why the speakers of PIE chose to introduce three genders.

Comment: I think, this is better asked as ‘What was the reason English evolved so that it *lost* the three types?’

Comment: So if german people use one article for all the nouns no problem will arose?

Comment: It was sufficiently helpful that it was *not dropped.* English dropped using genders and cases and received a less flexible word order.

Comment: There might be a small number of ambiguous words, but those will usually be resolved by including context. In colloquial speech it's quite common to shorten the indefinite article for masculine and neuter words to "n", and in some dialects the definite article is often shortened to "d", and no problems seem to arise in practice. There's [a good chance that in the future only "nen" will be used](http://scilogs.spektrum.de/sprachlog/kein-bock-auf-nen-interessantes-grammatisches-ph-nomen/), effectively removing the genders.

Comment: "English dropped using genders and cases and received a less flexible word order." What does it mean? Could you provide an example for me to understand?

Comment: Hard to explain that in a comment, but see e.g.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_language
In short, if a language has less inflection, it has to express grammatical structure through other means (e.g word order).

Comment: @Philipp *'nen Mann beisst 'nen Hund* is not exactly what I see as bright (or even probable) future of the German language.

Comment: @Eftekhari compare "Der Mann beisst den Hund" and "Den Mann beisst der Hund" vs. "The man bites the dog" and "The dog bites the man". And you get a good reason why German uses different and flexed articles.

Comment: @tofro Why three types? Why not just an article, for example just neutral?

Comment: @c.p. any kind for anyone who uses german for delivering ideas.

Comment: @Eftekhari There is not such a problem. Delivering ideas  **is** precisely mediated by a three-gendered grammar (not the only possibility, but it is what German *is*).

Comment: I still can't see any use of having three types of articles while I could use "der" for all of the nouns as far as I know and understand I couldn't provide an example that keeping all the nouns in one gender become problem maker as these genders are artificial.

Comment: @tofro My german is not good. Would you please help me to understand what exactly your mean is with the example that you provided?

Comment: @tofro As I get in german first two sentences are similar in meaning with the help of articles and second two sentences which are in English are not the same as we have not such articles in English. But my question is even this property in German language couldn't be just in one gender?

Comment: It could. But then it would be a different, hypothetical language and not German - So your question is kind of moot.

Comment: I can give you a specific example of how genders help me.  I'm a native speaker of English studying both German and Italian simultaneously and I find the gender markers, just like singular/plural markers,  useful in sorting out the syntax of sentences in these languages.  The genders give an clue about which words go together. It's not a perfect system of doing it but I find them helpful.  In a way they make the sentence structure clearer.

Comment: @AlMaki Please provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

The genders support the understanding, among others by making personal/reflexive pronouns less ambiguous. That puts more effort to the writer (and obviously to the learner, having to remember all the genders), but less effort to the reader. Since language is more often read than written, this is a benefit.

Example:

> Ein Igel traf ein Stinktier. Es biss ihn.

English:

> A hedgehoog met a skunk. It bit it.

As you will note, the second sentence leaves open in English, what was at the receiving end of the bite, while the German clearly states, that it was the hedgehoog.

Comment: So what is the problem if we use only one sex gender? Your answer doesn't cover the reason behind multiple genders.

Comment: A hedgehog met a skunk. She bit him.

Comment: I do not think this answers the question. If this was the reason for the grammatical genders, we would have even more of them. Your sentence is just a coincidence, what help would your theory be when a fox meats a badger?